# Contents of sidewaysfigure env is out of page with TRT pagedir

Tags: macros, luatex, right-to-left, patching

With this example (lualatex with TRT pagedir) the image does not appear. how to solve the issue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[demo]{rotating}

\pagedir TRT \bodydir TRT

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-a}
    \caption{text here}
    \label{fig:mine}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you use  `\pardir TRT  \textdir TRT` instead?

Comment: @SimonDispa to write Arabic document I need all `\pardir` ,  `\bodydir` , `\pardir` and `\textdir` with TRT

Comment: It is there, it has just been shifted off the bottom of the page.  Try a larger image.  \rotatebox (graphicx) is also shifted, even with a 0 degree rotation, and the origin keyword has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sidewaysfigure` environment in rotating package is built on  `\@xrotfloat`  command which save contents of environment in `lrbox`, the original defintion of  `lrbox` taken from latex.ltx

```
\def\lrbox#1{%
\edef\reserved@a{%
    \endgroup
    \setbox#1\hbox{%
      \begingroup\aftergroup}%
        \def\noexpand\@currenvir{\@currenvir}%
        \def\noexpand\@currenvline{\on@line}}%
  \reserved@a
    \@endpefalse
    \color@setgroup
      \ignorespaces
}
```

We need to redefine the command by adding `dir TLT` to the hbox

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[demo]{rotating}

\pagedir TRT \bodydir TRT

\makeatletter

\def\Lrbox#1{%
\edef\reserved@a{%
    \endgroup
    \setbox#1\hbox dir TLT{%
      \begingroup\aftergroup}%
        \def\noexpand\@currenvir{\@currenvir}%
        \def\noexpand\@currenvline{\on@line}}%
  \reserved@a
    \@endpefalse
    \color@setgroup
      \ignorespaces
}

\AddToHook{cmd/@xrotfloat/before}{\let\lrbox\Lrbox}
\AddToHook{cmd/@rotxdblfloat/before}{\let\lrbox\Lrbox} % for  double column floats

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-a}
    \caption{text here}
    \label{fig:mine}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This implements `sidewaysefigure` using `\rotatebox` and a `minipage`.  The problem is that `\rotatebox` swaps the height and depth values, which confuses LaTeX to no end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[demo]{rotating}

\pagedir TRT \bodydir TRT

\newenvironment{sidewaysfigure}{\figure[p]%
  \begin{lrbox}{0}%
  \minipage[c][\textwidth][c]{\textheight}}
{\endminipage\end{lrbox}%
  \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][\textheight]{\rotatebox{90}{\usebox0}}% swap height and depth
  \endfigure}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-b}
    \caption{text here}
    \label{fig:mine}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm searching for patching of sidewaysfigure from rotating package